# TestNG + Appium + Java : [TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class

Tags: automated-testing, java, testng, appium, mobile-automation

**Question:**

How to fix : [TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods.

More info:

My Automation is getting failed suddenly. I know it was working well before & even yesterday. Tried searching on Google but doesn't resolve my issue. Still facing below error:

> [TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods

Any one resolved this? If anyone is also facing same issue, please add your findings in comments.

**Environment:**

- Mac iOS Version : 10.12 [macOS Sierra]
- Appium : Appium1.8.1
- Xcode : 9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting this when doing a maven build. Please let us know the TestNG version as this is raised by TestNG.

Its a NoClassDefFoundError thrown by TestNG to gracefully handle the situation. ***Just check for maven dependency and class definitions.***

To be very specific TestNG throws this warning when it tries to get the methods of all classes in your project and the code flows to the Exception block.

Comment: Yes Thats right. But I have already gone through my mvn dependancies and all configurations. No errors and nothing changed still I'm facing this is bit scary. Have you face this issue in past? any other solution do you know?

Comment: I have not faced this issue. Can you share the exec log/ stacktrace. The line of execution says a lot of things. "Utils.log("[TestNGClassFinder]", 5, "[WARN] Can't link and determine methods of " + var4 + "(" + var12.getMessage() + ")");"